# Between mysql date_format not working

Tags: mysql, sql, date, between

I have this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users_profile` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '05-03-1996' AND '05-03-1915'
```

which should return two results which both have these dates in the dob column

```
08-02-1996
14-02-1996
```

But it dosen't return anthing!! What am I doing wrong!!??

Comment: This is why you never should store dates as strings. Dates are first class citizens in MySQL. Store your dates as dates and reap the benefits of MySQL's built in date functionality.

Comment: Convert the `dob` field to a `DATE` field.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you take a perfectly good date and convert it to a (bad) string for comparison?

Do the comparison as dates and put the constants in the right order:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users_profile` 
WHERE dob BETWEEN date('1915-03-05') and date('1996-03-05');
```

Also note that I changed the date format for the date constants to YYYY-MM-DD.  This is the ISO standard format for dates.  (Despite that), it is a really good idea to use.

I am assuming that `dob` really is a date, because that is what the function `date_format()` takes for its first argument.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: this version can also be faster since it does not require a full table scan.